# Move null elements of each row in a 2D array to the end of that row

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, null

Let's say I have a 2d array which looks like this:

```
[[O, X, null, O, O, null, null], [null, null, O, null, null, O, O]]
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
[[O, X, O, O, null, null, null], [O, O, O, null, null, null, null]]
```

I tried this, but it's not working:

```java
String[][] a = new String[row][col];
String[][] b = new String[row][col];

for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
        if (a[i][j] != null) {
            a[i][j] = b[i][j];
        } else {
            b[i][j] = a[i][j + 1];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some points to fix the problem

- You need to use `a[i].length` for inner loop
- `a[i][j] = b[i][j];` here you need to assign `a` value in `b`
- You need to use a counter index for `b` 2D array's every row and  whenever found not-null increment this after storing and remaining index are by defult null.

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  int indNew = 0; // Index for every row
  for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
    if (a[i][j] != null) {
      b[i][indNew] = a[i][j]; // store not null value
      indNew++;  // increase after storing
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that stands out to me is you never check the length of the inner array. Given the example, it will only ever check the first 2 elements.

```java
// Before
for (int j = 0; j < status.length; j++)

// Solution
for (int j = 0; j < status[i].length; j++)
```

As for the specific problem, you could do it by keeping track of the index of the first null and moving any elements you encounter to it.

```java
int lastEmpty = 0;

for (int j = 0; j < status[i].length; j++) {
    // Move to the best compressed position
    if (status[i][j] != null && status[i][lastEmpty] == null) {
        status[i][lastEmpty] = status[i][j];
        status[i][j] = null;
    }

    // Shift to always be the first null
    if (status[i][lastEmpty] != null) {
        lastEmpty++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over this array and for each row [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) out the *null* elements and collect the remaining ones [`toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction)) of the same length where the *nulls* go last:

```java
String[][] arr1 = {
        {"O", "X", null, "O", "O", null, null},
        {null, null, "O", null, null, "O", "O"}};

String[][] arr2 = Arrays.stream(arr1)
        .map(row -> Arrays.stream(row)
                // filter out null elements
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                // new array of the same length, nulls last
                .toArray(q -> new String[row.length]))
        .toArray(String[][]::new);
```

```java
// output
Arrays.stream(arr2).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

```
[O, X, O, O, null, null, null]
[O, O, O, null, null, null, null]
```

---

<sup>See also: [Remove null from old 2d array and put the not null elements in a new 2d array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65637889/14940971)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create new 2D array to store its updated version, `null` values can be simply moved to the end of each row and then use `Arrays.fill` to set null starting from the calculated index.

***update: the method can be generic***

```java
public static <T> void moveNulls(T[][] status) {
    for (T[] row : status) {
        if (null == row) {
            continue;
        }
        int id = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
            if (row[i] != null) {
                row[id++] = row[i];
            }
        }
        Arrays.fill(row, id, row.length, null);
    }
}
```

**Test**

```java
String[][] status = {
        {"aaa", null, "bbb", null, null, "ccc"},
        {null, "bbb", null, null, "ccc", "ddd", null, "eee"},
        {null, null, "fff", null, "ccc", "ddd", null, "ggg", null},
};

moveNulls(status);
for (String[] row : status) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
}
```

**Output**

```
[aaa, bbb, ccc, null, null, null]
[bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, null, null, null, null]
[fff, ccc, ddd, ggg, null, null, null, null, null]
```